# How do I get my embedded youtube video to play on the screen?

Tags: html, css, video, embedding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yaiR.png)I have embedded the youtube video following all the directions but once I see my page the video is unavailable to play. I have tried other versions of the video, and different ways of coding it but nothing has changed/worked.

I used the I frame code from the video. I was expecting it to show the video is ready to play and I would just need to click it to start but it just shows the grey screen with Video Unavailable play on Youtube. all of it is just in HTML if that gives more information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: that error message sounds like the video you are trying to play hasn't been enabled for Embed and can only be played on youTube site/app

Answer (score 1):

Try if this code works. You can get this iframe embed code of any YouTube video by clicking on "Share > Embed" below a video. Can't make any guesses on why it doesn't work for you since you didn't provide us any code.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/jNQXAC9IVRw" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I added a screenshot of the code. Sorry, this is my first time using this site was not sure how to add the photo.

Comment: The [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blkbLwvqugk) you are trying to embed is simply not available on YouTube. It could be private and only visible to you, or not existing at all.